# Removing location updates using a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-location

I have a service that constantly polls a webservice for some options. These options basically restart a LocationManager. This restart is done using a custom event which gets fired from a method used inside a thread.

Here is my custom event

```
public class OptionsChangedEvent extends EventObject {
    public OptionsChangedEvent(Object o){
        super(o);
    }
}
```

and the custom listener

```
public interface OptionsChangedListener extends EventListener {
    public void optionsChanged(OptionsChangedEvent evt);
}
```

the thread that runs in the service and polls for new options is the following

```
private Thread optionsThread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //Looper.prepare();
        while(true) {
            String opts = getOptsFromServer();
            if(!opts.equals(currentOpts)) updateOpts(opts); //the prob is here
            //Looper.loop();
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000) // sleep 10sec
        }
    }
}
```

Finally here is how I implement the listener inside my tracker.

```
locOpts.addOptionsChangedListener(new OptionsChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void optionsChanged(OptionsChangedEvent event) {
        Log.d("LOCATION_OPTIONS_CHANGED", "SUCCESS");
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                provider,
                update,
                0, mLocationListener
        );
    }
});
```

I had the following error which basically says that I need to use `Looper.loop` and `Looper.prepare` inside my thread.

```
12-03 11:31:39.544  26751-26843/com.test.location E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10370
Process: com.test.location, PID: 26751
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.<init>(LocationManager.java:221)
at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.<init>(LocationManager.java:221)
at android.location.LocationManager.wrapListener(LocationManager.java:844)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:857)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:454)
at com.test.location.trackers.LocationTracker$2.optionsChanged(LocationTracker.java:93)
at com.test.location.options.LocationTrackerOptions.notifyListeners(LocationTrackerOptions.java:22)
at com.test.location.options.LocationTrackerOptions.fromJSON(LocationTrackerOptions.java:34)
at com.test.location.MainService$5.run(MainService.java:219)
```

If I uncomment the Looper parts the thread works only once and I cant figure out why this happens.

### update

After some investigation I found that code that needs the message queue and creates this problem. Does anyone needed to do something like this? I would like to not change my design here if it possible.

```
private synchronized void notifyListeners(Object obj) {
    for (OptionsChangedListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.optionsChanged(new OptionsChangedEvent(obj));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple. I was missing the callback function.

```
locOpts.addOptionsChangedListener(new OptionsChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void optionsChanged(OptionsChangedEvent event) {
        Log.d("LOCATION_OPTIONS_CHANGED", "SUCCESS");
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                provider,
                update,
                0, mLocationListener,
                Looper.getMainLooper() // this was the problem

        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you try to update the UI in your callback method **updateOpts** ?

Looper prepare & loop using in other way, in case when you want to send tasks from UI thread to the backround thread, so you send message to the thread, and inside the thread process that message in handlemessage event of Handler.

try to avoid UI calls directly from your thread, maybe also try using runOnUIThread(...)
or AsyncTasks onPost to make the proper callback to the UI thread.

Comment: I am not trying to update ui. I just fire an event that will stop locations updates. Then it just starts location updates again. I have nothing to do with ui.